# Use Comma(,) as delimiter in rows in ORC file

Tags: hadoop, orc

I am creating an ORC file in Java. For each row I want the fields to be comma delimited. Here is my java code:

```
    ObjectInspector inspector = ObjectInspectorFactory.getReflectionObjectInspector(String.class,ObjectInspectorFactory.ObjectInspectorOptions.JAVA);
this.mWriter = OrcFile.createWriter(fs, fsPath, config, inspector, stripSize, CompressionKind.ZLIB, bufferSize,0);
this.mWriter.addRow(new Text("shekhar,saha")); 
this.mWriter.addRow(new Text("ram,shyam"));
this.mWriter.addRow(new Text("jhon,cena"));
this.mWriter.close();
```

Is this right way of creating it?

I am trying to load data in a Hive table. This is how I have created my table:

```
create table demo ( name1 STRING,name2 STRING ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");
```

But I am not able to load data. When I am reading data from the table its throwing class caste exception `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`

Comment: Does it yield the result desired by you? If yes, fine. If no, please tell us what is wrong.

Comment: @TAM I am trying to load data in a Hive table. This is how I have created my table: create table demo (
 name1 STRING,name2 STRING  
 )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");   But I am not able to load data. When I am reading data from the table its throwing class caste exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: Similar question I have posted before. You can look into that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622287/issues-loading-data-into-hive-from-a-orc-file